# How to open D:\a\r1\a\ on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running Cypress in one of my release stages and it gives me this output:

```
Finished processing:  D:\a\r1\a\_ClientWeb-Build-CI\ShellArtifact\tests\integration\cypress\videos\onboarding.spec.js.mp4 (0 seconds)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is the path name relative to the app service? If I have a app service called `randomname` and run the Cypress Stage on that `randomname` app service should I be able to find tCypresshe output in `randomname.scm.azurewebsites.net`.
2. If I go into the `scm` debug console and I do `cd D:\a\` I get:

> cd : Cannot find path 'D:\a\' because it does not exist.

So how do I actually access my Cypress test results?

I've also tried archiving the files into a zip file:

[image]

In the output of the task step I see:

```
Creating archive: d:\home\testing\somefile.zip
```

But when I try to access the `D:/home/testing` folder on my `appname.scm.azurewebsites.net` I get:

> cd : Cannot find path 'D:\home\testing' because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `D:\a\r1\a` is inside the hosted agent that run the release pipeline, is not in your application.

The same thing is for the zip file, when you specify `d:/home/...` is in the agent.

After the release is finish all the files are deleted, so you need to save the file in another place (maybe in azure?) during the pipeline, for example, with "Azure File Copy" task.

Comment: When I check my `download artifact step` I see this line `Downloading ShellArtifact/cypress-testing-files.zip to D:\a\r1\a\_ClientWeb-Build-CI\ShellArtifact\cypress-testing-files.zip` then when I navigate to `https://*.azurewebsites.net/cypress-testing-files.zip` I can download the file.

In my Cypress testing results I see `D:\a\r1\a\_ClientWeb-Build-CI\ShellArtifact\tests\integration\cypress\videos\onboarding.spec.js.mp4` but when I navigate to https://pb-14300-`https://*.azurewebsites.net\tests\integration\cypress\videos\onboarding.spec.js.mp4` I get a `page not found`

Comment: Because the "download artifacts step" is downloading the files to the agent, not to your app.

Comment: Would it be possible to extract the files to the agent instead of the app in the release pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. now the cyperss output is in the agent.

Comment: Let me start again. I think I mixed some stuff up. You're saying the issue I'm having is that the Cypress test results files are placed in the agent and not in my app. And the files in the agent are removed after completion. My question then is how do I move the files from the agent into the app so I can view them in the browser.

Comment: Ok, now I understand :) can you share the task in the pipeline that upload the app to azure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195109/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-shayki-abramczyk).